# Multiple cPanel Users on 1 Domain

Tags: linux, centos, cpanel, vps, whm

I run a website on a VPS with WHM and cPanel.

My client wants me to give him access to cPanel. However; I don't want to give away my account that I need for managing the domain, nor do I want to share my account with another person for security reasons. How, do I create another user to access cPanel?

I've read lots of pages, saying you can't have more than 1 user, but I find this very hard to believe. Surly having multiple cPanel logins, is a normal requirement for any hosting service?

*The already have FTP access.

If anyone know if this can be done, or a work around, this would be very helpful. If it can't be done. Does anyone have any advice of what I could say to my client? If I say they can't have access, I could lose them.

Many thanks,

Mark

Comment: Why is cPanel and WHM licensing? I have a licence. It's not even an issue.

I need to know if there is a way of creating another user in cPanel for a particular domain. I can only find a way to create 1 user login, yet I need 2!

Answer (score 4):

There is an outstanding feature request at Cpanel for giving multiple Cpanel logins for a single account.

See: https://features.cpanel.net/topic/multiple-cpanel-logins-cpanel-subusers

At the time of writing, Aug 2020, the above request is 7 years old and the original thread on Cpanel forum is dated Oct 2012 so I don't see this happening in a hurry.

For my own clients, I have written an explanation here https://www.jucra.com/whmcs/knowledgebase/165/ as well as a solution for providing developer access to your account without providing Cpanel log in.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have found the answer?

If I change the login details for my client to be the cPanel user... As the server root administrator in WHM, I can still access his cPanel as the Root User! So effectively, that means you can have 2 users for cPanel.